# Google Custom Search JSON Api Response Limit

Tags: c#, google-custom-search

I'm using Google Custom Search API with JSON Response, but it only gives me 100 results, my account is free. Do you know if i change my account status to paid account, can i get more than 100 results?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#Pricing:

> Paid Usage
>
> Any usage beyond the free usage quota will fail if you are not signed up for billing. Once you have enabled billing, you will continue to receive 100 free queries per day. However, you will be billed for all additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day. If you need additional quota, please request additional quota from the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question, I wanted to ask the same but it's hard to structure the question correctly. I'm working on an app at the moment and the result mechanism just 'drops dead' during the evening. I have to wait until the following day before I can do any searches, it's incredibly frustating. I have not yet checked for an error code at this point in time as I'm very sure that the problem is quota related.